# How to uninstall or remove recently-installed packages

Tags: apt, x11, uninstall

I installed the development packages for X11 today and now want to remove them. I do not remember the exact name of the package that I installed. I installed by running `apt-get install ...` and now want to remove the development package using `apt-get purge --auto-remove <name of package>`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you installed them today, they’ll all be listed in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. Look through that, identify the packages you don’t want, and remove them.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt remove --purge $(ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | head -n 10 | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -n1 basename | sed -e "s/\.list$//")
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

`ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list` - gives you the list of packages sorted by time

`head -n 10` - gives you the first 10 packages

`awk '{print $9}'` - selects the 9th column which is the file path

`xargs -n1 basename` - gives the filename

`sed -e "s/\.list$//"` - gives you the package name

Comment: Thanks! Be aware that the `sed` replacement gets in conflict with packages containing "list" in their name (like libkf5messagelist5abi1). Anyways, I dumped the intermediate results into files and fixed this manually before passing it on to `apt remove`.

Comment: I modified the answer to use `sed -e "s/.list$//"` Hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: look at bash command history: `history`.

Future: use `equivs-control` to create a `.deb`, it makes it easier to un-install.