# procedure for updating linux kernel with a test kernel I built

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

**Background**

I have Debian linux on a Starfive VisionFive 2 SBC that I am experimenting with. The VisionFive 2 is a RISC-V SBC and Starfive provides a Github repository with all the necessary materials to build a kernel.

The instructions to build an image suitable for an SD card are at [Building StarFive Debian image](https://rvspace.org/en/project/Building_StarFive_Debian_Image). The actual source repository is at [Github - starfive-tech/VisionFive2](https://github.com/starfive-tech/VisionFive2).

I've built an image for an SD card and everything is running as documented in an article, [VisionFive 2 RISC-V - Building the Linux Kernel](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372699/VisionFive-2-RISC-V-Building-the-Linux-Kernel), I wrote several months ago. I've added a number of other bits such as Apache2 web server that appear to be running fine.

I'm using WSL with Ubuntu on Windows 10 for my build environment.

The VisionFive 2 uses the `u-boot` loader rather than `GRUB`. I can access the console of the VisionFive 2 using a USB/TTY adapter that came with the VisionFive 2 bundle I purchased. I'm using the `gtkterm` application connecting to `/dev/ttyUSB0` under Linux on an OrangePi 5 Plus to host the `gtkterm` session as well as to remote shell into the VisionFive 2 using `rsh`.

So to be clear, I'm using a WSL on a Windows 11 box to build and transfer the image and I'm using Linux on an OrangePi 5 to be able to see the console output from the VisionFive 2 since Windows 11 doesn't want to recognize the USB/TTY adapter but Linux does. I did have an initial problem with `gtkterm` as documented in this Stackoverflow post, [How do I connect to a terminal to a serial-to-USB device on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560899/1466970)

**Question: is the following a proper procedure to test a linux kernel?**

I now want to update my linux kernel with a test kernel that I have built from source of the current linux kernel release that contains a few changes. I used the following procedure but am not sure if this is actually a good procedure.

- edited the linux kernel `Makefile` with `vi` to change `SUBLEVEL=0` to `SUBLEVEL=11`
- rebuilt the kernel which created a file `linux-image-5.15.11-starfive_5.15.11-starfive-8_riscv64.deb`
- used the `psftp` utility to put the file to the VisionFive 2 SBC
- used `PuTTY` to open a command shell and navigated to the folder where I put the `.deb` file
- used `sudo apt install ./linux-image-5.15.11-starfive_5.15.11-starfive-8_riscv64.deb`
- rebooted the VisionFive 2 with `sudo reboot` and crossed my fingers

This seemed to work fine.

**Followup question:** does the version number always need to change in order to update the linux kernel?

**The results**

Now when I do `sudo ls -l /boot` I see the following list of files:

```
user@starfive:~$ sudo ls -l /boot
[sudo] password for user:
total 43672
-rwx------ 1 root root 4455561 Oct 30 05:12 System.map-5.15.0-starfive
-rwx------ 1 root root 4461300 Feb 19 14:00 System.map-5.15.11-starfive
-rwx------ 1 root root  213287 Oct 30 05:12 config-5.15.0-starfive
-rwx------ 1 root root  212806 Feb 19 14:00 config-5.15.11-starfive
drwx------ 4 root root    2048 Oct 30 06:33 dtbs
drwx------ 2 root root    2048 Feb 19 14:17 extlinux
-rwx------ 1 root root 9226555 Feb 19 13:50 initrd.img-5.15.0-starfive
-rwx------ 1 root root 9226555 Feb 19 14:17 initrd.img-5.15.11-starfive
-rwx------ 1 root root     406 Oct 30 01:21 uEnv.txt
-rwx------ 1 root root 8478959 Oct 30 05:12 vmlinuz-5.15.0-starfive
-rwx------ 1 root root 8428381 Feb 19 14:00 vmlinuz-5.15.11-starfive
user@starfive:~$
```

And the `uname -a` command shows `5.15.11-starfive` rather than `5.15.0-starfive`:

```
user@starfive:~$ uname -a
Linux starfive 5.15.11-starfive #8 SMP Mon Feb 19 14:00:22 EST 2024 riscv64 GNU/Linux
user@starfive:~$
```

I changed the `Makefile` for the linux build because when I tried the above procedure with the resulting file of `linux-image-5.15.11-starfive_5.15.11-starfive-8_riscv64.deb`, listing the contents of `/boot` on the SBC showed that the time date stamp on the file `vmlinuz-5.15.0-starfive` did not change. I also saw an install error about the file `System.map-5.15.0-starfive` could not be replaced during the install.

Now it appears that I have two versions of the linux kernel in the `/boot` directory.

When I reboot the VisionFive 2 and watch the `u-boot` logs displayed on the console, I can see a several seconds pause as `u-boot` displays a list of images before it continues with the default. It appears the default is my build however I can choose the original build and when I do and the device fully comes up and I remote shell in using `rsh -l user starfive` (the VisionFive 2 has a host name of `starfive` visible on my local area network), I can see that `uname` indicates the original image.

```
user@starfive:~$ uname -a
Linux starfive 5.15.0-starfive #1 SMP Mon Oct 30 09:12:59 UTC 2023 riscv64 GNU/Linux
user@starfive:~$
```

**Addendum I: Removing the test linux build**

The first step I did was to reboot the VisionFive 2 with a `gtkterm` session attached to the console and when `u-boot` displayed the list of available images, I picked the original image. The device then booted from that image as I verified with the `uname` command.

Using the procedure mentioned in [How to uninstall or remove recently-installed packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510811/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-recently-installed-packages) I removed the test build that I had installed. I first verified the package name by using the command `apt list "*starfive*"` which displayed the installed packages for the linux images. I then did a `sudo apt remove` specifying the package name of my test build.

I rebooted the device watching the console and the menu displayed by `u-boot` no longer listed my test build. I did not enter any input allowing the default boot to go. Checking in `/boot` using `sudo ls -l /boot`, the test build image was no longer there. When I used the `uname-a` command the original image name was displayed with its date of October 30.

Comment: doesn't  GRUB show two entries?

Comment: When you say you updated the kernel Makefile, did you edit it yourself, or did you update the kernel sources to a newer version?

Comment: @jsotola this embedded device uses `u-boot` rather than GRUB. However I have a setup with an OrangePi with Linux connected to the VisionFive 2 with a USB/TTY cable and I can see the boot process using `gtkterm`. The `u-boot` loader does display a menu of images available for several seconds before continuing with a default. It does show both images, the original one and my test build.

Comment: @StephenKitt I modified the kernel Makefile by hand using `vi` text editor. I did update my Github clone from the Starfive repository but the kernel version appears to be the same until I modified it.

Comment: OK, so that wouldn’t update the kernel; the kernel version is updated when new releases are made, see for example [v5.15.0](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.15&id=8bb7eca972ad531c9b149c0a51ab43a417385813) (which is tagged as v5.15) and [v5.15.11](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.15.11&id=fb6ad5cb3b6745e7bffc5fe19b130f3594375634). Your rebuilt kernel declares its version as 5.15.11 but it is still really 5.15.0.

Comment: @StephenKitt I understand that it is the same release of the kernel however the new kernel I built did have a few changes. This would be similar to my wanting to modify the current release of linux and then test a new build with those changes. It appears that I must also modify the version number in the `Makefile` or the `apt install` will not work. That is the procedure I used. My question is whether this procedure is what people use when testing a linux build that is the current version but with a few changes.

Comment: Oh, OK, I thought part of what you were trying to do was upgrade to the actual 5.15.11 release. For your own changes you should use `EXTRALEVEL`, not `SUBLEVEL`.

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you. I'll try that out today. I want to start spending some time with learning the linux kernel. However since it's massive, I have to figure out some small part and to start with a simple change or two.

Comment: @StephenKitt I modified a variable `EXTRAVERSION` in the linux Makefile which resulted in generating a `.deb` file named `linux-image-5.15.01-starfive_5.15.01-starfive-9_riscv64.deb` and I was able to use `sudo apt install` to install it after transferring the file to the device. When I rebooted the device, the `uname -a` command showed the expected version number along with the expected date, `Linux starfive 5.15.01-starfive #9 SMP Wed Feb 21 12:33:47 EST 2024 riscv64 GNU/Linux`. Are the procedures I used appropriate for testing my own linux build?